# How to change line spacing in footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, setspace

I have a document with line spacing 1.5. But I want the footnotes line spacing 1. How could I do this? I tried the package `setspaces` but does not allow me this option.

Answer (score 10):

The package you need to load for the purpose at hand is called `setspace`, not `setspaces`. After loading it, you can issue the command

```
\onehalfspacing
```

to set up one-and-one-half line-spacing in the main body of the text; text in footnotes will remain single-spaced.